# Force https except for one directory

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I'm using the following .htaccess file to force any page request to https://

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

How could I force https for all directories/pages except the directory "/domain" ?

I can change the main htacces or create a new one in the /domain directory, the easy way, but how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should get what you need.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !domain [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```