# Use HTTPS except for some folders (different domain)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

This is my **htaccess**:

```
# All access http to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# all access with www to without www and https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

# all access redirect to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I have `3` sites

**1:** Main site on root `/` with this htaccess and with HTTPS

**2 and 3:** other sites without SSL certificate (http access) inside folders like  `/mysite.com.br` and other site on folder `/myothersite.com.br`, I want to redirect all access on main site / to SSL, but not redirect subfolders of other sites.

I've tried this but does't work https://stackoverflow.com/a/17638936/2761794

*Note: I think that before redirecting to the correct site, the host first passes the main site and reads the htaccess on root folder `/`, and as the htaccess in the root is not configured properly, the redirect is being done incorrectly...*