# How to force redirect to HTTPS except one folder with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, web

I have searched for this question but no answers are workable for me.

I am trying to redirect my entire website from HTTP to HTTPS except for the items in the folder /games/.

I would like to do the opposite for /games/, redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP.

This is what I tried but it just shows an infinite loop.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !games [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638645/force-https-except-for-one-directory) but its not working-->                                           
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !games [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Answer (score 4):

You can use this rule as **first rule** in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !games [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# rest of your rules go here
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache when testing this change.

Comment: Thank you. But this only works for Homepage and pages in /games/. For other pages in other directories (e.g. http://example.com/file/index.html), it will become an infinite loop.

Comment: You've misunderstood it or didn't explain your problem properly. This rule **skips** if request has `games` in it. Why would it become infinite loop once request has already become `https` after redirect.

Comment: This rule must be your very first rule below `RewriteEngine` line.

Comment: I don't know what happen, everything works now except for Homepage. My screenshot for Homepage: http://prntscr.com/gmof6a

Comment: If this is first rule then homepage would also be redirected. Make sure you clear browser cache,